# How can I force IPA deployment over ITunes to my IPad

Tags: xcode, ipad, deployment, adhoc, ipa

I am trying to simplify the ad-hoc deployment of my IPad app as much as possible. I can create a IPA file from within XCode without much trouble with Product->Archive and Archive->share, and when I click on the IPA file it tries to import it into ITunes it asks if I want to replace the existing app (which is an older version of the same app).

After I do that I force a sync from ITunes but the app on my IPad is still the older version. The only way I got it to work is doing the following:

1) Delete old version from ITunes

2) Delete old version from IPad

3) Resync ITunes

4) Import IPA file into ITunes

5) Resync Itunes

Is there an easier way to deploy a new version of something to an IPad using an IPA file without having to go through all this? I tried changing the product name and bundle display name, but it didn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about iOS 4.x.x or the iOS 5 Developer Preview?